# &#x43a - что это за символы, как расшифровать?

Tags: html, шифрование, unicode, decode, utf

Хочу расшифровать текст из таких символов? Где копать? Что это???

(P.S.) из-за этого едет верстка на этом сайте и не могу смотреть посты

[image: плывет верстка]

Comment: Ну покажите нам хоть что-нибудь, текст, код(мин. воспроизводимый)

Comment: @Prog залил картинку, добавил в описание

Comment: в данном случае текст означает "Пожаловаться на эту рекламу"

Answer (score 1):

По стандарту HTML символ `&` говорит что все до символа `;` является текстовым "названием" символа. Например последовательность `&amp;` — это символ с "именем" `amp` — амперсанд, то есть `&`, таких символов с человекочитаемыми названиями не много, их можно найти в стандарте и любом справочнике.

Если "имя" символа начинается с символа `#`, это значит, что остальная часть имени — это число, обозначающее номер символа. Например `&#38;` — это тот же амперсанд, символ с кодом 38.

Если число в "имени" начинается с `x`, значит это шестнадцетиричное число. Например, `&#x26;` — это символ с кодом 26h, то есть 38 в десятичном представлении, то есть тот же самый амперсанд.

Таким образом последовательность `&#x43a;` из заголовка — это символ с кодом 043Ah, то есть 1082. Смотрим таблицу Unicode — это маленькая русская `к`. Во всех языках программирования есть функция получения символа по его коду.